# MySql JOIN table as content?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of contact details (name, province, etc) and I have a table of one word answers and they have the same user id. I want to join the one word answers into the contact details so I get.

```
first name, last name, province, email, list of one word answers separated by a , or another character
```

I know I need to do a sub select but how can I take all the values and separate them by a character and then return it as something in the main select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the help of [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) :

```
SELECT name, province, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word) FROM answers a WHERE a.user_id = c.user_id) AS words 
FROM contacts c
```

Comment: my bad: `If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows. `